# Azure App Service won't serve via HTTP

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have an ASP.net MVC app running on Azure App Service ... I've searched for the answer, but have not found it ... my app seems to always force HTTPS redirect, no matter what.  All the docs say it should serve content via HTTP by default, but it does not.  Most everyone has the opposite problem of needing to redirect HTTP to HTTPS.

I need Azure App Service to do the following:

1)  Serve static Default.htm page via HTTP, without redirecting to HTTPS

My app has a custom domain and no SSL for the custom domain.  I want the URL http://example.com/Default.htm to serve the static page, not redirect to HTTPS to serve the static page. I will use azurewebsites domain when I want users to be in HTTPS.  I want to use my custom domain name to serve a static home page for users arriving at my site.

As far as I can determine, I do not have any app extensions installed (such s https redirect extension), or anything in web.config to force https, or any RequireHTTPS attributes ... can anyone explain why plain old regular boring HTTP doesn't work here?

Thanks

Comment: I may have found the answer ... in Azure app portal, under settings for this app, "App Service Authentication" was enabled.  This seems to force https.  When disabled, my static content is served via HTTP as expected.

Comment: Curious about your scenario, why do you want to use http instead of https ?

Comment: I only want http to serve a static home page for my custom domain which does not have an SSL cert.  Any links into the app which would require https will be directed to the azurewebsites.net domain, which has SSL

Comment: @ChrisBradford have you found a solution? I have the same issue: custom domain and no https cert. Also in my case "App service authentication" forces the whole site to HTTPS.